# How to Concatenate strings in Array using Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have following sveral arrays which each of them consists into a String.

```
x = ["t", "o", "d", "a", "y"]
y = ["i", "s"] 
z = ["s", "u", "n", "d", "a", "y"]
```

my output should be like following:

```
x = [today]
y = [is] 
Z = [sunday]
```

in together: today is sunday

How can i get expected array using ruby?

Comment: What is the `today` in `[today]` – a string? Then it should be `["today"]`.

Answer (score 4):

You will want to use the `#join(separator)` method.

See the official ruby docs for [Array#join](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-join)

Example:

```
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'].join('')
=> "hello"
```

A good place to start learning the basics of Ruby is at [Code Academy](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-ruby).

I also recommend [dash](https://kapeli.com/dash) for browsing documentation offline!

Comment: You can just call `join`, the empty string argument isn't needed.

Comment: @Stefan is right and it should be called without an argument when an array is being joined without a separator

Answer (score 2):

For final your output,

```
[x, y, z].map(&:join).join(' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [.join()](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-join) method like this:

```
x = ["t", "o", "d", "a", "y"]
y = ["i", "s"] 
z = ["s", "u", "n", "d", "a", "y"]

x.join()
=> "today"
y.join()
=> "is"
z.join()
=> "sunday"
```

Then do this:

```
x.join + y.join + z.join()
=> "todayissunday"
```

Or combine `x`, `y`, `z` into one array and call join on it, like this:

```
Array(x + y + z).join
=> "todayissunday"
```